# How to make a function usable by a class but not by it's subclasses in python

Tags: python, class

I remember that there is some sort of syntax that will make a function of a class only callable by that class and not by any subclasses that inherit the functions of that class, but I can't recall exactly what it is and google has been of no help to me. Can anyone remind me how I would go about doing this?

Comment: That's not the done thing in python, so there's no simple way to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you have a subclass of something, it should have all of the methods of that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enforce the privacy, but [starting a method name with double underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/600110) is the idiomatic Python way to indicate that the method should not be used by subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking of. If I did ever need to strictly enforce the usage of the function to one class I would indeed just use Hyperboreus' answer, but the underscore syntax is the way I had in mind.

Comment: @user3002473 Glad to hear that, because my answer may be correct, but I wouldn't advise using it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but I think it is a bit of an anti-pattern:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        if type(self) != A:
            raise NotImplementedError('Thou shalt not invoke this here method.')
        print('good')

class B(A): pass

A().f()
B().f()
```

But actually, please don't use it. Stick to the normal underscore and dunder notation with the implied name-wrangling. We are all adults around here. Especially as my approach can be easily broken from the outside:

```
type_ = type
type = lambda x: A
B().f()
type = type_
```

Comment: Just a quibble, but shouldn't you be raising `NotImplementedError()` rather than `NotImplementedError`?

Comment: @SamMussmann Well any answer to a python question involving enforced privacy, will be unidiomatic I fear.

Comment: @Hyperboreus True enough.

Comment: @SamMussmann And you can also work around my approach quite easily. Snug in a `type = lambda x: A` before the calls, and all enforced privacy goes down the john.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is not an answer to your question, but you should really consider rethinking your object structure since you are violating the common principles of object oriented programming.

Comment: What in specific would I be violating?

Comment: Inheritance is semantically a "is a"-relationship - and not a "is a except of"-relationship